# shows an error l"cannot read property 'servers' of undefined "

Tags: javascript

sorry i was a noob then

```
const client = new Discord.Client();
const token = process.env.DISCORD_BOT_TOKEN;
const activities = [
`${this.client.servers.cache.size} servers!`,
`${this.client.channels.cache.size} channels!`,
`${this.client.guilds.cache.reduce((a, b) => a + b.memberCount, 0)} users!`
];


client.on('ready', message  => {
        let i = 0;
setInterval(() => this.client.user.setActivity(`${activities[i++ % activities.length]}`, { type: 'WATCHING' }), 10000);
  console.log(`Thank you for starting the mighty Towers. Please keep this page open to keep it running bro!!! This is ${client.user.tag}! hosted by Abhinav`) 
});

client.login(token);
```

[Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DWiPg.png)

[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DWiPg.png): [image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/DWiPg.png] - this is an pick

this is the error `${this.client.servers.cache.size}` servers!

Comment: Note that Java and JavaScript are two different things. Don't confuse them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error is happening because `this.client` is not defined. You have defined `const client` so it is not accessible as `this.client` but as just `client`

Changing `this.client` to `client` in the code should solve your problem.

```
    const client = new Discord.Client();
    const token = process.env.DISCORD_BOT_TOKEN;
    const activities = [
    `${client.servers.cache.size} servers!`,
    `${client.channels.cache.size} channels!`,
    `${client.guilds.cache.reduce((a, b) => a + b.memberCount, 0)} users!`
    ];


    client.on('ready', message  => {
        let i = 0;
        setInterval(() => client.user.setActivity(`${activities[i++ % activities.length]}`, { type: 'WATCHING' }), 10000);
        console.log(`Thank you for starting the mighty Towers. Please keep this page open to keep it running bro!!! This is ${client.user.tag}! hosted by Abhinav`) 
    });

    client.login(token);
```

Comment: hey thanks it worked but a new error pops up
its shows that cache is undefined 
what should i define cache as?